# Updating the values in an array contained in a class/struct - SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

I'm creating an app that contains ingredients for foods (simplified version of the app for context of the question). However, I am not sure how to updates values of an array (ingredients).

I have the following struct for each Food that contains a ID(UUID), a name(string), and ingredients(array). I've created a master view for each food as a @State variable and then a detail view which has an edit button that takes you to an edit view with the selected food as a @Binding var.

public struct Food: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable, {
public var id = UUID()

```
var name: String
var ingredients: Array<String>
```

}

In the edit view I'm able to update the name of the food but I can't figure out how to update each individual ingredient. This is the line giving me trouble in the edit view:

```
ForEach(food.ingredients, id: \.self) { ingredient in
    List {
        TextEditor($ingredient)
                                        
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the issue? you can't edit ingredients or can't figure out how to store value in array?

Comment: You'll need to iterate over indices with `ForEach(food.ingredients.indices, id: \.self) { ... }` and then use `$food.ingedients[index]` as a binding to pass to `TextEditor`

Comment: @PratikPrajapati Yes I can't edit the ingredients. I'm not sure how to edit an array stored in a struct.

Comment: try mutating func in struct.

Comment: @NewDev That's it! Appreciate it 